# How to append to a multi dimentional list

Tags: python

How do I make this work? Im pulling a list of int values and trying to add years to the list.

```
dataList = []
read = open("USPopulation.txt", 'r')
population = read.readline().rstrip('\n')

year = 1950
i = 0
maxPopulation = 0
minPopulation = sys.maxsize
avgPopulation = 0
total = 0
maxPop_Year = 0
minPop_Year = 0

while population != "":
        year += i
        dataList[i].append(year)
        dataList[i].append(population)
        i += 1
        population = read.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

Error

```
line 8, in <module>
    dataList[i].append(year)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sample Input

```
151868
153982
156393
158956
161884
165069
168088
171187
174149
177135
179979
182992
185771
188483
```

Im trying to get this running first before i work on the output of the information. But what i intend to do is process the information to find the maximum amount of population and the minimum, also the average between the years and display that information.

```
    for i in range(len(dataList)):
    if dataList[i][1] > maxPopulation:
        maxPopulation = dataList[i][1]
        macPop_Year = dataList[i][0]
    if dataList[i][1] < minPopulation:
        minPopulation = dataList[i][1]
        minPop_Year = dataList[i][0]        

print("The year", maxPop_Year, "had the most population with", maxPopulation)
print("The year", minPop_Year, "had the least population with", minPopulation)
```

Error

```
if dataList[i][1] > maxPopulation:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output for that input, as well as any errors encountered when running your code with that input.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly provide more details for people to look into your question properly.

Comment: Added more information

Answer (score 0):

```
dataList = []
read = open("USPopulation.txt", 'r')
population = read.readline().rstrip('\n')
year = 1950
i = 0
while population != "":
    year += i
    #An empty list needs to be append to add items
    #fix begin
    dataList.append([])
    #fix end
    dataList[i].append(year)
    dataList[i].append(population)
    i += 1
    population = read.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: dataList.append([])

Answer (score 0):

The complete code for min, max and avg (but uses an inline list rather than a file reader)
You should use a hash table or associative array rather than a list.
The statement `year += i` is also not correct as it will make `year` increase in an unexpected fashion -- 1950, 1951, 1953, 1956, 1960 ...

```
dataList = {}
input = [151868,153982,156393,158956,161884,165069,168088,171187,174149,177135,179979,182992,185771, 188483]
year = 1949
min_popl = -1
max_popl = -1
minyr = -1
maxyr = -1
total_popl = 0
i = 0
for popl in input:
    year += 1
    i += 1
    dataList[year] = popl

    total_popl += popl

    if min_popl == -1 or popl < min_popl:
      min_popl = popl
      minyr = year

    if popl > max_popl:
      max_popl = popl
      maxyr = year

print("Minimum popl [{}] in year [{}]".format(min_popl, minyr))
print("Maximum popl [{}] in year [{}]".format(max_popl, maxyr))
print("Average popl [{}]".format(total_popl/i))
```

Output of the above -

```
Minimum popl [151868] in year [1950]
Maximum popl [188483] in year [1963]
Average popl [169709.7142857143]
```